# Android: Accessing activity intents parent functions

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Android: Accessing intents parent functions.

I have an activity that opens another activity though the intent class. I have to access the parent class functions (In order to change images from the child class). So far I have:

(In parent)

```
public static Activity _activity;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    _activity = this;
}
```

Then in the child activity I've got:

```
private Activity _getImageActivity;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    _getImageActivity = GetImageActivity._activity;
}
```

This seems to work but _getImageActivity doesn't access any of the parents public functions.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you can solve your problem, of changing images of a parent activity, is by launching the `child` activity using `startActivityForResult()`. Once you are done with the actions in the child activity your control will return to `onActivityResult()` of the parent activity where you can change the images.

Following is the official link:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,int).

You will get many examples of its implementation in the net.